# How to get Variable from User input String in PHP?

Tags: php

I am getting input string from user with custom variable names and now i want to parse this string. Please help how can i do this.

This is the string user can provide me

```
//User input

$input = "Lorem ipsum text {{someVariable}} lorem ipsum";

//Now i want to use at my side as

$input = "Lorem ipsum text ".$someVariable." lorem ipsum";

echo $input;
```

someVariable is a variable name, i will find its value at my side, user only provides me variable name in his input string.

Thanks:)

I used the regular expression but unable to do as i want. I think i can do this with regex but how i don't know.

Comment: Update your question with your current code, also examples of possible inputs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can adjust the **$accepted_words** [regex](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.syntax.php) with attention :

```php
<?php

$accepted_words = '[a-zA-Z]+';

//User input
$input = "Lorem {{ipsum}} {{text}} {{someVariable}} lorem ipsum";

preg_match_all("#\{\{($accepted_words)\}\}#", $input, $variables);
$variables = end($variables);

print_r($variables);
// Array ( [0] => ipsum [1] => text [2] => someVariable )
```